# Activity as a listener and memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-activity

I have the following framework for my application:
1. a Network thread that runs in the background (a queue) for issuing request and get async responses. The thread is started and stopped in the Application Object so it's leaving through out the whole application.
2. a DataManager which is also a member of Application and has different DataManagers for the data types i retrieve from the network. the data manager itself is the listener for the responses from the network so it's safe until the application itself dies.
3. this is the problematic part. Some of my Adapters and part of my Activities are DataListeners for my DataManagers, that means that the data manager keeps a reference to them.

When a phone call or some other phone event occurs i've noticed that the activity is usually in paused and not destroyed and so receives my events, which is ok. the problem starts when landscape\portrait is changed. since i keep a referenced to the activity in an Application bound object, the activity can't be destroyed on one hand, BUT the event is still getting to the listener, only the wrong one...
Basically i can fix that issue by removing the listener in onDestroy and retaining configuration boolean to tell me that request was allready issues and i just need to put a listener and try to retrieve the data from the data manager.

However :-) i was wondering how android handles this cases usually, if for example this was a Service running. or if the Service is a local Service that used Bound and passed on the Activity as a Listener to the network Event, the same things happen, untill the listener is not removed the Activity is leaked and lives on, but without it, no way to get callbacks from the network...
an Intent requires serilaztion and deserilazation of data which can be heavy (Bitmaps for example?)

And anywa, asuming i send an intent on each respose i get, how do i get the intent to the Activity (i know of getIntent, but if i get another one , not related, do i get it as an 'event' ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so let me describe the problem and the solution i found in more details.
The problem:
I have a Service\Network Thread that needs to notify Activities that sent requests through it that either request or Error has arrived in an Async way. Using Listener Pattern requires me to set listener before or when i send a request like so:

```
mNetService.setRequest(request, this);
```

where this is Activity that implements my listener Interface.
But doing it this way requires me to remove the listener from the service in onDestroy and returning the listener, if i ever sent a request back in onCreate\onResume, but the response can also arrive exactly when the activity is not listening (landscape\portrait event) which requires me to keep the Error\Response in the service until some1 picks it up and resets it.

The solution i found:
using Broadcasts and BroadcastReciever.
this is only part of the solution but it let you have a listener to broadcasts (that can be specific for a certain class type meaning Activity) and action.
Since all of my Activities inherit a base Activity class i've made they all have a BroadcaseReciever inner class that listens on certain action in it's filter.
is i enable the listening in the C'tor of my Activity the listener will be registered in onResume and deregister in onPause.
If the listener gets onRecieved event it will call a method in the Activity (which i can override in my specific activty) and pass it the Intent i got which can contain all the data from the response.

The only missing part is what happens if the Activity dies for a second and only then the broadcast arrives ? ah, that's a problem, so android intorduces Sticky Broadcasts that stays there untill you remove them with removeStickyBroadcast(Intent), so when is ent broadcast from my service i send Sticky broadcast, when the Activity gets my Broadcast it removes it so it wont stay around and mislead the activity about new response that arrived.
The only problem with it is if i send a request, don't wait for the response and goes to the next Activity right away, in this case when i'll go back to that Activity it will think it got the response. Didn't find a proper solution to that just yet. But it's better then my previous solution.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather it's customary on Android to remove yourself from listener lists when the activity is destroyed. It's kinda error-prone, but I think it's the generally accepted way to do it.

You could imagine your service accepts only one listener, which may or may not fit your case, and when the activity restarts its registering with the DataManager would overwrite the old activity which would in turn be garbage collected. The drawback is, you don't free the activity memory if it is destroyed but the service lives on, so it's probably better to just remove the activity from listeners.

Comment: my thoughts exactly.. i think this would be my approach, i kinda thought intents could ease the task. but i'm not sure if it eases it or coplicates it.

Answer (score 1):

Android development is rather different from other platforms (e.g. BlackBerry). I'm not able to give you a quick silver bullet solution, however here are my thoughts on this:

> Some of my Adapters and part of my
>   Activities are DataListeners for my
>   DataManagers, that means that the data
>   manager keeps a reference to them.

OS kills Activities according to their [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife). So you should avoid keeping a handle to an `Activity` in another object which is supposed to live after the `Activity` is destroyed by OS. Otherwise you'll get memory leak.

Also keep in mind `Application` sublass instance does not always live for the whole application session (a session from a user perspective). If your app goes in the background, for example, due to an incoming phone call, then your entire process can be killed. See details [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#proclife). As soon as you `Application` sublass contains some state which is not persisted if process is killed you may mistakenly expect your handles to point to some non-null entities. However after going to foreground (and process restore) those may just be nulls because a new instance of `Application` sublass has been created by OS.

Comment: you are righ about several tings here, but saying the obvious i allreayd know, i know my design is not trival or 100% conforming android design guidelines, but that's the design. i can chane some small things like unregistering or maybe use intents as times instead of regitering regualr listeners. but i need to follow the guidelines i wrote above.
regarding killing the application, u are righ of course, but it's small chance and when the application restores untill it fiinishes it's onCreate no other actiivty will be restored, so what i can do is check if my request are stll in queue or resend